# Converting SMAP h5 file to GeoTiff

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdal, h5py, geotiff

I am trying to convert .h5 SMAP file to geotiff, but I keep getting

```
 File "<ipython-input-17-d6b129648904>", line 1
gdal_translate -a_srs "EPSG:3662" -a_ullr -20037508.3428 10018754.1714 20037508.3428 -10018754.1714 'HDF5:"SMAP_L3_SM_P_E_20170711_R15060_001.h5"://geotiff/' SMAP_L3_SM_P_E_20170711_R15060_001.tif
                                ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I keep getting different answers on where to put the quotations.
Also, I just want to confirm that if I use gdal_translate and specify that the output will be GeoTIFF, it will create a Geotiff file on my computer.
I checked these resources already, but I am still stuck:

- [How to transform HDF5 to geotiff using gdal_translate or gdalwarp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933598/how-to-transform-hdf5-to-geotiff-using-gdal-translate-or-gdalwarp)
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330602/converting-hdf5-to-geotiff-using-gdal
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253923/how-to-fix-the-reprojection-from-ease-2-grid-product-smap-to-geographic-coordina)

Comment: That looks like a shell command - it's meant to be used from something like bash or the Windows command prompt, not Python. It looks like you're in IPython, so you might be able to use it with a `!` at the front.

Comment: I tried to run this os.system(gdal_translate -a_srs "EPSG:3662" -a_ullr -20037508.3428 10018754.1714 20037508.3428 -10018754.1714 'HDF5:"SMAP_L3_SM_P_E_20170711_R15060_001.h5"://geotiff/' SMAP_L3_SM_P_E_20170711_R15060_001.tif'), but it did not create any file. Can you help me ?